# How to disable editing input in Haml

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I want to disable an input so it is not editable once the user clicks edit.

`student_form.html.haml`:

```
%div{:class => 'form-group row'}

    %div{:class => 'form-group col-3'}

        = label :student_id, :student_id, 'Student Id'

        = text_field :student_id, :student_id, :maxlength => 6, :class => 'form-control'
```

`edit.html.haml`:

```
     = form_tag student_path(@student), :method => :put do

            = render :partial => 'student_form'


            = submit_tag 'Save Changes', :class => 'btn btn-primary'

        %p
            = render partial: 'shared/cancel_button', locals: {path: student_path(@student)}
```

Comment: By 'not readable'  do you mean not show this field / partial at all or just disable field - making it not-editable?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Is there a problem, or just a goal? What isn't the code doing correctly? Haml generates HTML, it doesn't know anything about what the user has done once the form is presented to the browser. To make a change when the user does something you'll either need to submit the input back to your server or use JavaScript. There's no JavaScript in your question.

Comment: I mean like gray out the input in edit.html.haml so its no editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `disabled: true` option in the `text_field` in order to  disable field on the Form, so it will only display value, won't allow to edit it.

`student_form.html.haml:`

```
    = text_field :student_id, :student_id, :maxlength => 6, disabled: true, :class => 'form-control'
```

If you are reusing partial `student_form` in other places and you want to have it editable there, you can pass this value through `locals`, same way as you doing it in the other partial.

Comment: If I just wanted to gray out a single input instead of disabling the inputs. How would I do that in edit.html.haml

Comment: @EricReeves - just use option which I suggested above `disabled: true` for a field which you want to disable. Hope that helps